# Make a child class define an object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I was wondering if there was a way to make a child class of an `abstract` class define an object, and in this case an `ArrayList`. This might have a simple answer, and I'm not looking enough, but I can't find anything! 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the code that demonstrates your idea?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Can't you just declare it as a `protected` field of the abstract class? Thereby forcing all children to have it?

Comment: If you mean multiple inheritance, then no Java doesn't do that.  However, some IDEs will take the grunt work out of delegation by generating most of the code for you.

Comment: @4castle What I mean is having a different ArrayList for each class that extends this parent abstract class, not having multiple parents.

Comment: Your question is not clear. One of the main purpose of Abstract classes are to inherit them so that you can enforce the abstract methods.What is the issue you having?What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Denis I just want to be able to force child classes to define an ArrayList

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? It doesn't make a ton of sense considering the individual instances will not share a non-static list.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I guess your right this is just me being stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `ArrayList` as a `protected` field of the abstract class. Any subclass will be able to access it using the `super` qualifier, or by name if it isn't being shadowed by a local variable.

```
public abstract class Person {
    protected List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    public void callCellPhone() { ... }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    public void callFriends() {
        // friends is defined in the super-class
        // "super" is an optional qualifier here
        for (Person person : super.friends) {
            person.callCellPhone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean for Student to extend Person?

Comment: @Jhonny007 Whoops that's important xD